After switching to Android API 34 in my Xamarin android project,I get the error one of receiver_exported or receiver_not_exported should be specified
After switching to Api 34 in my Xamarin android project, I get the error 'one of receiver_exported or receiver_not_exported should be specified when a receiver isn't being registered exclusively for system broadcasts'.
Xamarin.Essentials nuget package :1.8.1
enter image description here
 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
       
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;
     
         
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Instance = this;
            //var options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            //  .SetApplicationId("1:865419492128:android:4d581aa626e7df54093545")
            //  .SetApiKey("AIzaSyDpq3kXLbpzGwrtMsvH3hM3GKvGXQJMhvE")
            //  .SetDatabaseUrl("https://pianodentalclinic-839ce.firebaseio.com")
            //  .SetGcmSenderId("865419492128-vdkjet53af3kurcjsv621g00jgbdk5v5.apps.googleusercontent.com")
            //  .SetStorageBucket("pianodentalclinic-839ce.appspot.com")
            //  .Build();
            Plugin.CurrentActivity.CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity = this;
            FirebaseApp.InitializeApp(this);
            Rg.Plugins.Popup.Popup.Init(this);
         
            this.Window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen);
            //ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.Android.Platform.Init();
            var config = new FFImageLoading.Config.Configuration()
            {
                VerboseLogging = false,
                VerbosePerformanceLogging = false,
                VerboseMemoryCacheLogging = false,
                VerboseLoadingCancelledLogging = false,
                Logger = new CustomLogger(),
            };
            ImageService.Instance.Initialize(config);
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);

            DependencyService.Register<ToastNotification>();
            //if(Build.VERSION.SdkInt > BuildVersionCodes.Tiramisu)
            //{
                //Context context = Android.App.Application.Context;
               // IntentFilter intent;
                // BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver;
                //ContextCompat.RegisterReceiver(context, consoleCmdReceiver, intent, ContextCompat.ReceiverExported);
                //Context.RegisterReceiver(consoleCmdReceiver, IntentFilter, ReceiverExported);
            //}
            //RegisterReceiver(consoleCmdReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ActionRun));
            ToastNotification.Init(this);
            CachedImageRenderer.Init(true);
            CachedImageRenderer.InitImageViewHandler();
 
            LoadApplication(new App());

            //string tkn= CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.Token; 

            //FirebasePushNotificationManager.ProcessIntent(this, Intent);

        }

Among the solutions was to install xamarin.essentials 1.8.0-pr.2108.1. I installed it, but it gave the warning that the package was not restored and the error continued.

You should use AndroidX in order to use the ReceiverNotExported flag as mentioned in the error
And in order to use the AndroidX flag, you need to RegisterReceiver using AndroidX as well, so your will need to look like this:
  var flags = AndroidX.Core.Content.ContextCompat.ReceiverNotExported;
  AndroidX.Core.Content.ContextCompat.RegisterReceiver(this, consoleCmdReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ActionRun), flags);

this should reference your ApplicationContext if your code isn't inside the activity you want to use it in
Also as you mentioned, the Connectivity functionality in <=1.8.0 of Xamarin Essentials is causing that issue, so make sure you fix that as well

Alternatively you can also use this RegisterReceiver(context, consoleCmdReceiver, intent, (ActivityFlags)ReceiverFlags.NotExported); as shown here
